# Regular expression in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, replace, yahoo-pipes, capturing-group

I want to know what regular expression should be applied to replace `1 - 55 of 55` to only get `55` in Regex module of yahoo pipes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Match

```
\d+ - (\d+) of \1
```

with

```
$1
```

Comment: Thanks guys I tried, but still getting the same 1 - 55 of 55 , below is the pipe URL plz check
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=f2caf57c625f0030dd6f5bd412ef5b17

Answer (score 1):

You can try to match this:

```
\d+ - (\d+) of \1
```

And replace with `$1`, which is what group 1 captured.

The `\d` is the digit [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), `+` is one-or-more [*repetition*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). The `(…)` is a [*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and the `\1` refers back to what that group matches. So this will match strings like:

```
num1 - num2 of num2
        |        |
        \________/ must match
```

#### References

- [pipes.yahoo.com - Regex module documentation](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#Regex) - has a very good tutorial
- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - a more comprehensive regex tutorial

---

#### Variation

This pattern is a slight modification that is more flexible in its whitespace matching:

```
\d+\s+-\s+(\d+)\s+of\s+\1
```

It's similar to the previous pattern, but wherever we had just a literal space character before, we now use `\s+`, which is a pattern that matches a non-empty sequence of any number of whitespace characters. This includes newlines, tabs, etc.

If the third number doesn't have to be the same as the second number, then simply use another `\d+` instead of `\1`.

```
\d+\s+-\s+\d+\s+of\s+(\d+)
```

Now this will match strings like `"1 - 20 of 149"`, being liberal with the spacing. The bracket is now moved to match the third number, so if the entire string is to be replaced by that number (`149` in this case), simply replace with `$1`.

If you want to capture all 3 numbers individually, you can write something like this:

```
(\d+)\s+-\s+(\d+)\s+of\s+(\d+)
\___/       \___/        \___/
  1           2            3
```

Now the first number is captured by group 1, second number by group 2, and third number by group 3.

Comment: Thanks I tried, but still getting the same 1 - 55 of 55 , below is the pipe URL plz check http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=f2caf57c625f0030dd6f5bd412ef5b17

Comment: @Balaji: see my latest revision. I tried the new pattern and it works. http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=011b2556313cb14f1690cfd13e1f3fb3

Comment: Great it worked, Thanks a Million, but what if its 1 - 20 of 149, now how can I extract just 149, in this case num1 and num2 doesn't match

Comment: @Balaji: the problem is that the spaces in the string is not actually just a simple space. You can try matching `.*` and see that it doesn't capture the whole string. There are some newlines in there, but it's not rendered as such by the viewer. Using `\s+` takes care of that problem.

Comment: @Balaji: if the third number doesn't have to be a match, then instead of referring back to the second number by using `\1`, just use `\d+` again. See latest revision.

Comment: Thanks, I tried \d+ in the last it gave 20 instead of 149
here is the pipe http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=0ab08d7739a057a374d9c42e1472212f

Comment: oh sorry I missed the brackets, Thanks a lot, u made my day :) bye

Comment: @Balaji: Don't forget to upvote and accept an answer that helps. That's the arrows to the left of my answer. It gives people incentives to help others.